# Dividing one equation by another

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is from Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight. [image]
I don't understand how this is  done. Can you explain?

Comment: difference of two squares

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Comment: To me the explanation given in the book seems rather unclear. It really should have mentioned that we are using the difference of two squares factorization. Otherwise it's not clear why dividing each member of (2) by the corresponding member of (1) would be a valid thing to do. I'm a bit afraid that other students who read this (not you) might think that if $a+b = x$ and $c+d= y$ then $a/c + b/d = x/y$, but of course that's usually not correct.

Comment: I first thought so.

Comment: Now try to derive the cartesian equation for an ellipse. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that (2) could be factored as

$$ (3x^2-4x+34)-(3x^2-4x-11) = (\sqrt {3x^2-4x+34} -\sqrt {3x^2-4x-11})(\sqrt {3x^2-4x+34} +\sqrt {3x^2-4x-11})=45$$

Now dividing by $(1)$ results in $(3)$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use the identity 
$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b) $$